# Unable to Launch League of Legends using PlayOnLinux

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

After installing **League of Legends** on **PlayOnLinux 4.2.10**, I double click to run the application. But it just gives me the followings.

[image]

How to play League of Legends on **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**?

Comment: Can you upload the files mentioned in the **Report Details** window?

Comment: This could be a directx problem. I do not know about play on linux but the newest version of directx that runs on crossover is directx 9.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is the new launcher so this is what works for me:

#### Using Wine 2.6 for League of Lagends

1. Open the **Wine Versions Manager > Tools > Manage Wine Version**.

   [image]
2. Install **Wine 2.6**.

   [image]
3. Set Wine version to `2.6` for **League of Legends**.

   [image]

#### Before Launching Game

1. Go to `~/PlayOnLinux's virtual drives/LeagueOfLegends/drive_c/Riot Games/League of Legends/RADS/system`.
2. Edit `user.cfg` like this:

   ```
   disableP2P = true
   leagueClientOptIn = no
   replayPopUpShown = yes
   ```

Comment: I encountered a program error: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24438799/.